# XPath for a descendant based on properties of another descendant

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<level1>
  <level2>
    <level3-0>
      <level4-0 attr="hello"/>
    <level3-1>
      <level4-1>
...
  <level2>
```

Is it possible in single xPath to define access to concrete grand-grand-child of ancestor having another concrete child with specified attributes?

In example, say `level2` is multiple under `level1`. I need access to `level4-1` because `level4-0` has attribute `attr="hello"`. Structure under `level2` is known.

If it not possible to do it in single xPath, can I have another XPath for finding index of `level2` under level1?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, given your example, this single XPath,

```
/level1/level2[.//level4-0[@attr='hello']]//level4-1
```

Will select the `level4-1` element contained somewhere beneath a `level2` element that contains a `level4-0` element with a (hopefully unique) `hello` `attr`.